# Does log4j2.properties file support parameters

Tags: apache-spark, logging

Currently we use property.basePath = ${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}

We have use case where we are thinking to use common log42.properties file. Wanted to know if there is support to pass app_name as a parameter/argument to be replaced in the log4j2.properties file

Sample lines in log4j2properties file:

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger

logger.app.name = ${appName}
logger.app.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger
```